# Are there also strong admonitions against the wealthy in the Jewish Bible?

Tags: tanach, christianity

In Christianity, there are several passages containing warnings or even threats directed at wealthy individuals, cautioning them about the state of their souls. For instance:

Mark 10:24:

> But Jesus answered and said to them, 'Children, how hard it is for those who trust in riches to enter the kingdom of God! 25 It is easier for a camel to go through the eye of a needle than for a rich man to enter the kingdom of God.

The Magnificat

> Mary's song of praise in Luke 1:51-53, echoes 1 Samuel 2:8: 'He has brought down rulers from their thrones but has lifted up the humble. He has filled the hungry with good things but has sent the rich away empty.'

Is this a Christian concept, or do similar warnings appear in the Tanach as well?"

Comment: Is it ok to quote the Christian books on this site?

Comment: @ElonMusk looks like comparative religion. Voting to close.

Comment: @ElonMusk yes it is ok if relevant to the question

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150254/discussion-on-question-by-suslik-are-there-also-strong-admonitions-against-the-w); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with wealth in Judaism, as long as you use it wisely and give 10-20% of your income to charity.  Enjoy the rest:

> גַּ֣ם כׇּֽל־הָאָדָ֡ם אֲשֶׁ֣ר נָֽתַן־ל֣וֹ הָאֱלֹהִים֩ עֹ֨שֶׁר וּנְכָסִ֜ים וְהִשְׁלִיט֨וֹ לֶאֱכֹ֤ל מִמֶּ֙נּוּ֙ וְלָשֵׂ֣את אֶת־חֶלְק֔וֹ וְלִשְׂמֹ֖חַ בַּעֲמָל֑וֹ זֹ֕ה מַתַּ֥ת אֱלֹהִ֖ים הִֽיא׃ -- Also, whenever a man is given riches and property by God, and is also permitted by Him to enjoy them and to take his portion and get pleasure for his gains—that is a gift of God. [Ecclesiastes 5:18]

Comment: a fantastic view! I like it

Comment: For a complete picture, giving charity is not the only ethical action wealthy people are expected to do by the Torah

Comment: Any reason to think this verse represents normative Judaism?  The same work you cite also says there's no judgement after life כֹּל אֲשֶׁר תִּמְצָא יָדְךָ, לַעֲשׂוֹת בְּכֹחֲךָ--עֲשֵׂה:  כִּי אֵין מַעֲשֶׂה וְחֶשְׁבּוֹן, וְדַעַת וְחָכְמָה, בִּשְׁאוֹל, אֲשֶׁר אַתָּה הֹלֵךְ שָׁמָּה which is outright heresy

Comment: The commentaries take this proverb, like many in Kohelet and Mishlei, to be a metaphor, talking about spiritual gifts, rewards and delights etc.